# All columns in row are identical except one

Tags: sql

I have data in table something like this...

```
Transaction Type|Batch ID|Batch Number|Item Number|Organization Code|Source System Code|Source System Reference|Attribute Group Code       |ATTRIBUTE_CHAR1                |
----------------|--------|------------|-----------|-----------------|------------------|-----------------------|---------------------------|-------------------------------|
SYNC            |        |            |230-000134 |LOGITECH         |                  |                       |2x_P3_CATALOG_VALUES_ATTGRP|PWA (SMT+TH)                   |
SYNC            |        |            |230-000134 |LOGITECH         |                  |                       |Common Part Attributes     |                               |
SYNC            |        |            |230-000134 |LOGITECH         |                  |                       |Common Part Attributes     |EXT - GSR (generic for AMR 3PL)|
SYNC            |        |            |230-000134 |LOGITECH         |                  |                       |Inventory Org              |                               |
```

As shown above I have all columns identical except `Attribute_Char1` for `Common Part Attributes`. How to apply such distinct that it will eliminate such rows too where only 1 column is not identical, most probably would have null values. So if there is another column having such type of data with extra row where all columns are identical except 1 or 2 with null value it would not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

One option is aggregation:

```
select
    transaction_type,
    batch_id,
    batch_number,
    item_number, 
    organization_code,
    source_system_code,
    source_system_reference,
    attribute_group_code,
    max(attribute_char1) attribute_char1
from mytable
group by
    transaction_type,
    batch_id,
    batch_number,
    item_number, 
    organization_code,
    source_system_code,
    source_system_reference,
    attribute_group_code
```